# What will happen if Chinese yuan turn floating exchange rate system?

Tags: exchange-rates

The excange of Chinese yuan is controled by Chinese government in part now. 
What will  happen  if  Chinese yuan turn floating exchange rate system?

Comment: Right now the Yuan is being suppressed, so if left to free market forces the Yuan will probably appreciate. The Chinese trade surplus will probably fall dramatically, and inflation around the world will rise as Chinese goods will now be more expensive.